# newenvironment with braces split between start and end

Tags: errors, environments, braces, syntax

I'm defining a command for placing figures in the margin. A simple version follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\margin}[1]{\marginpar{#1}}
\begin{document}
\margin{Figure goes here}
\end{document}
```

However, I'd like to make this command an environment, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{margin}{\marginpar{}{}}
\begin{document}
\begin{margin}
Figure goes here
\end{margin}
\end{document}
```

Here I'm naïvely using `marginpar{` as my start code and `}` as my end code. But these braces end up getting paired with the braces used to delimit `newenvironment`'s arguments, so I get an error.

How should I make this environment?

Comment: See the `environ` package, it is made for gathering the contents of an env into a macro

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `environ` package like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{margin}{\marginpar{\BODY}}
\begin{document}
\begin{margin}
Figure goes here
\end{margin}
\end{document}
```