# Error while nesting two environments

Tags: errors, environments, nesting

I'm trying to nest two environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{innerEnviron}
    {INNER \BODY{} INNER}
\newenvironment{outerEnviron}
    {OUTER \begin{innerEnviron}}
    {\end{innerEnviron} OUTER}

\begin{document}
\begin{outerEnviron}
content
\end{outerEnviron}
\end{document}
```

I expect to get

> OUTER INNER content INNER OUTER

but instead I get

```
LaTeX Error: \begin{innerEnviron} on input line 11 ended by \end{outerEnviron}.
```

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Addendum: I cannot change my `NewEnviron` to a `newenvironment`, because otherwise I would end up in the situation of [newenvironment with braces split between start and end](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275755/newenvironment-with-braces-split-between-start-and-end).

Comment: newenviron defined environments have to look ahead to find `\end{zzz}` so it needs to be explicit in the document. You could just define both via `\newenvironment` in this case, but perhaps your real use case is different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\begin{innerEnviron}` want to see an explicit `\end{innerEnviron}` for knowing where to stop. You can use the internal commands, instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{innerEnviron}
    {INNER \BODY{} INNER}
\newenvironment{outerEnviron}
    {OUTER \begingroup\innerEnviron}
    {\endinnerEnviron\endgroup OUTER}

\begin{document}
\begin{outerEnviron}
content
\end{outerEnviron}
\end{document}
```